# Building a embedded C client for AWS IoT with C SDK: mbedtls libraries

Tags: c, amazon-web-services, sdk, iot, mbedtls

I am not able to build the sample application (subscribe_publish_sample) written in C for IoT on AWS.
On page ...
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-embedded-c-sdk.html
... there it is said that I have to download all required third-party libraries.
The instruction in a readme-file in deviceSDK/external_libs tell me that I have to ' ... download mbedTLS from the official ARMmbed repository and place the files here'.
What libraries from the mbedtls-development are necessary for that ?
Thanks

I already tried copying the include and the libraries folder from mbedtls-development without success.

Comment: I managed to get it running when I copied the complete directory of mbedTLS into folder aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/external_libs.

Comment: Only answers resolve questions, not comments.  So you should post that as a self-answer and then accept it.